# Function to hide multiple divs

Tags: javascript, function, html, hide

I hope, somebody can explain me where I'm wrong with my code...So I have this function:

```
function divdisplay(element){
  if(document.getElementById(element).style.display == 'none'){
     document.getElementById(element).style.display = 'block';
     for (var i=0; i<NUMBER_OF_DIVS; i++)
       document.getElementById(i).style.display = 'none';
  } else
     document.getElementById(element).style.display = 'none';
```

The function displays the divs just fine, but the hiding part is the problem. I want to hide several other `<divs>`. The `ids` of these other `<divs>` are simple numbers, which is why I try to address these elements with the variable `i`. But when I click on `<div>` #1 while `<div>` #2 is already visible, only `<div>` #1 appears and `<div>` #2 does not disappear.
The `<divs>` look like this:

```
    <div id="1" style="display:none;">
      <a href="javascript:divdisplay(1);">
        <img src="..."/>
      </a>
    </div>

    <div id="2" style="display:none;">
      <a href="javascript:divdisplay(2);">
        <img src="..." />
      </a>
    </div>

    <div id="3" style="display:none;">
      ...
```

And they first appear when the corresponding link

```
    <a href="javascript:divdisplay(1);">
    <a href="javascript:divdisplay(2);">
    <a href=...
```

is clicked.

The image in each `<div>` is linked to the function again, so a click on the image inside the `<div>` hides it again, but a click on another link does not make the visible `<div>` disappear again. Where did I go wrong?

Thanks in advance anyway.

Comment: you do know numeric IDs are only legal in HTML5 ?

Comment: no, I didn't know that. Changing it right away.

Comment: so I changed it to IDs like div1, div2, etc, but now the divs won't appear at all.

Comment: perhaps you should better explain what it is you actually want to happen?

Comment: Also, if you've updated the ids, make sure you also update the code so instead of `document.getElementById(i)` it says `document.getElementById('div' + i)`.

Comment: No worry, I did change the code to document.getElementById('div' + i). Alnitak, I want one element of the website to appear when I click on one link. When I click on a specific link inside this element, I want it to disappear. However, I have several of these elements I want at any one moment only one to be visible, so the visible one should disappear A) when I click on the "close"-link and B) when I click on the "appear"-link of any other of those elements.

Answer (score 1):

Why you don't use Jquery? You only have to add a class to each div you want to hide/show

```
<div class="test">content here</div>
```

and now you can use `show()` and `hide()` from jquery.

`$(".test").show();` and `$(".test").hide();` will show/hide all div's with the class `test`.

You also check out [show()](http://docs.jquery.com/Show) and [hide()](http://docs.jquery.com/Hide).

In addition you have chance to add an effect to your `show()` and `hide()` function.

Comment: Have you ever checked out jQuery's call stack on a function like that?
It's rather bloated for a simple functionality like this. I prefer not to use libraries for something that can be written in a few lines of code. (You'll need a similar amount of code to add the "Show only div x" logic with jQuery)

Comment: You are absolutely right. If you only want to use it for this case it's "to much". But often there more places to use it. I don't think that the OP only has to hide div's :)

Answer (score 0):

This function loops through all your divs and only shows the one you specify in `element`

```
function divdisplay(element){
    for (var i=0; i<NUMBER_OF_DIVS; i++){
        var div = document.getElementById('div'+i);
        if(i == element){
            div.style.display = 'block';
        }else{
            div.style.display = 'none';
        }
    }
}
// As Alnitak suggested, this can be condensed into:
function divdisplay(element){
    for (var i=0; i<NUMBER_OF_DIVS; i++){
        document.getElementById('div'+i).style.display = (i == element)? 'block' : 'none';
    }
}
```

I prefer not to use jQuery in small functions like this, because it'll save you from loading a library (-1 HTTP request), and the native functionality is simply faster. (Not significant at this amount of code, but still)
Assuming you're not using jQuery already, that is. If you are, this will work:

Assuming you add a class to all elements like this:

```
<div class="hideMe" id="1" style="display:none;">
  <a href="javascript:divdisplay(2);">
    <img src="..." />
  </a>
</div>
```

jquery:

```
function divdisplay(element){
     $(".hideMe").hide();
     $("#"+element).show();
}
```

Comment: I mean refactor the `document.getElementById('div' + i)` code outside of the `if`

Comment: much better :)  FWIW, I would have used the ternary operator to chose the appropriate style value.

Comment: True, but I prefer to stick to if-else's when explaining code. Easier to understand.

Comment: I wouldn't have put it all on one line, though ;-)